# TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsonp' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I created a function that saves data in my database.

```
  $scope.addMovie = function() {

    'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=releases'
    // Search for release dates using the ID.
    var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
    var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text()
    var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
    var append_to_response = '&append_to_response=releases'
    var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
    var url = base + movieID + '?api_key=' + apiKey + append_to_response + '&callback=' + callback;

    $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        if (status == 200) {

          $scope.movieListID = data;
          console.log($scope.movieListID);

          var releaseNL;

          for (var i = 0; i < $scope.movieListID.releases.countries.length; i++) {
            var release = $scope.movieListID.releases.countries[i];
            if (release['iso_3166_1'] == 'NL') {
                releaseNL = release;
            }
          }

          if(typeof releaseNL === 'undefined'){
            // With release date

            Notification($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd, maar heeft nog geen Nederlandse premiere datum.');

            createMovie.create({
              title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
              release_date:   $scope.movieListID.release_date,
              image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
              movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
            }).then(init);

          } else {
            Notification.success($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd.');

            createMovie.create({
              title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
              release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
              image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
              movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
            }).then(init);
          };

        } else {
            console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
        }
      })

      $(".search_results").fadeOut(250);

      $scope.searchquery = null
  };
```

I want to remove this code from my controller to service. So I created a "addMovieService.js"

```
(function(){
  "use strict";

  angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('addMovie', [

    function($http, $q, $scope){
      return{
        add: function(){

          'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647?api_key=a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&append_to_response=releases'
          // Search for release dates using the ID.
          var base = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/';
          var movieID = $(event.currentTarget).parent().find('.movieID').text()
          var apiKey = 'a8f7039633f2065942cd8a28d7cadad4&query='
          var append_to_response = '&append_to_response=releases'
          var callback = 'JSON_CALLBACK'; // provided by angular.js
          var url = base + movieID + '?api_key=' + apiKey + append_to_response + '&callback=' + callback;

          $http.jsonp(url,{ cache: true}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

              if (status == 200) {

                $scope.movieListID = data;
                console.log($scope.movieListID);

                var releaseNL;

                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.movieListID.releases.countries.length; i++) {
                  var release = $scope.movieListID.releases.countries[i];
                  if (release['iso_3166_1'] == 'NL') {
                      releaseNL = release;
                  }
                }

                if(typeof releaseNL === 'undefined'){
                  // With release date

                  Notification($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd, maar heeft nog geen Nederlandse premiere datum.');

                  createMovie.create({
                    title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
                    release_date:   $scope.movieListID.release_date,
                    image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
                    movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
                  }).then(init);

                } else {
                  Notification.success($scope.movieListID.original_title + ' is toegevoegd.');

                  createMovie.create({
                    title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
                    release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
                    image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
                    movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id
                  }).then(init);
                };

              } else {
                  console.error('Error happened while getting the movie list.')
              }
            })

            $(".search_results").fadeOut(250);

            $scope.searchquery = null
        }
      }
  }])

})();
```

And in my controller I now have,

```
$scope.addMovie = function() {

  addMovie.add();

};
```

Now when I fire the addMovie function I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'jsonp' of undefined`. Can someone explain what´s going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not injecting `$http` properly. You're using an array as the second argument in `factory(...)`, but you're not giving it the names of the injected fields.

Possible fix:

```
angular.module('addMovieseat').factory('addMovie', ['$http', '$q', 
    function($http, $q) {...}]);
```

EDIT: I removed `$scope` since it can't be injected into factories.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. I thought I didn't need to do that since I do that in the controller, Thanks for the tip. If I add '$http" the initial error is gone. But when I also add "$scope" to the second argument I get another error, `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- addMovie` any ideas?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma: Oh, sorry. You can't inject `$scope` into factories :). Scopes are only created for directives (or by hand, but that's very unusual to do).

Comment: does that mean I can't use scope inside a factory? Because I  place the data from the JSONP request inside a scope. It looks like the create function shouldn't be in the factory, is that correct?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma: Well, this is a topic for a longer discussion. In general it's not good to pass the scope to a service/factory, since the service should be independent of that, and should just return some data. That way, you can easily reuse the service in different controllers and directives (and possibly even apps). But if you really want to, you can always pass the scope to `add` (`addMovie.add($scope)`).